# Selenium Web Driver: Extracted Chrome Browser logs are incomplete

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm writing browser tests for a Vaadin application with help of Selenium. The Chrome browser log console in development utilities shows logs of different log levels (TRACE, SEVERE, WARNING). Following code sets up my test driver:

```
@RunOnHub
public abstract class SmokeTestCase extends ParallelTest {
    ...
        final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setHeadless(false);
        final LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
        logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
        chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
        setDriver(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
    ...
```

My Vaadin applications runs in DEV mode. With following code I'm trying to retreive all browser logs via the test driver:

```
final LogEntries entries = this.driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
for (LogEntry entry: entries) {
  System.out.println(entry);
  final String line = String.format("[%s] - %s - %s", entry.getLevel().getName(), entry.getTimestamp(), entry.getMessage());
  if (entry.getLevel() == Level.SEVERE) {
    System.err.println(line);
  } else {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I only receive WARNING and SEVERE. INFO and TRACE are missing. What am I doing wrong?

My approach is simular to this one: [How to get Chrome browser console log [INFO] entries with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563331/how-to-get-chrome-browser-console-log-info-entries-with-selenium)

We also tried to enable and request the log types `DRIVER` or `CLIENT` - but they are empty.

Chrome Driver log file:

```
[1563798293,491][INFO]: [9a5a5e7219d7e4e784ad1ccf205a31df] COMMAND GetLog {
   "type": "browser"
}
[1563798293,491][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.evaluate (id=2292) 143AE946F7F1974C2722E6519DB6CBA5 {
   "expression": "1",
   "returnByValue": true
}
[1563798293,491][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.evaluate (id=2292) 143AE946F7F1974C2722E6519DB6CBA5 {
   "result": {
      "description": "1",
      "type": "number",
      "value": 1
   }
}
[1563798293,491][INFO]: [9a5a5e7219d7e4e784ad1ccf205a31df] RESPONSE GetLog [ {
   "level": "SEVERE",
   "message": "http://.../APP/connector/0/443/icon/save-document_24.png - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 ()",
   "source": "network",
   "timestamp": 1563798292695.0
}, {
   "level": "SEVERE",
   "message": "http://.../APP/connector/0/444/icon/container_3_24.png - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 ()",
   "source": "network",
   "timestamp": 1563798292695.0
}, {
   "level": "WARNING",
   "message": "http://.../VAADIN/vaadinPush.js?v=8.7.2 0:40212 \"Websocket closed, reason: Normal closure; the connection successfully completed whatever purpose for which it was created. - w...",
   "source": "console-api",
   "timestamp": 1563798292711.0
}, {
   "level": "SEVERE",
   "message": "http://.../APP/connector/0/448/icon/save-document_24.png - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 ()",
   "source": "network",
   "timestamp": 1563798292711.0
}, {
   "level": "WARNING",
   "message": "http://.../VAADIN/vaadinPush.js?v=8.7.2 0 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more...",
   "source": "deprecation",
   "timestamp": 1563798292776.0
} ]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since chromedriver 75.0.3770.8 `CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS` is deprecated. Use `goog:loggingPrefs` instead.

Comment: You are the hero!

Comment: Working with version 83, `goog:loggingPrefs` is the way to go.