# How to get console.info logs via webdriver?

Tags: java, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I try to get console info logs via webdriver and i can't, but I see the "warn" logs. Here is my simplified settings to start the chromedriver:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
LoggingPreferences loggingPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
loggingPrefs.enable( LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL );
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability( CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingPrefs );
options.merge( capabilities );
ChromeDriverService.Builder builder = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
        .usingDriverExecutable( new File( "my path to chromedriver" ) )
        .usingAnyFreePort()
        .withEnvironment( ImmutableMap.of( "DISPLAY", ":0" ) );

ChromeDriverService service = builder.build();
webDriver = new ChromeDriver( service, options );
webDriver.get( "my site for testing" );
```

I set up my page to execute next code:

```
console.warn("warn")
console.info("info")
```

I tried to stop my test on breakpoint, or add some waits/thread.sleep(), so I ensured that it was executed. 
Now, while I execute `webDriver.manage().logs().get( LogType.BROWSER )`, i get only one log entry, the "warn" log:

> [2019-11-26T13:51:55+0200] [WARNING] console-api 0:8 "warn"

So my question is what I should do to get "info" logs?

Some additional info:

- Chrome build 77.0.3865.90
- Chromedriver build 77.0.3865.40
- selenium 3.14.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar question with the answer: [Selenium Web Driver: Extracted Chrome Browser logs are incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146129/selenium-web-driver-extracted-chrome-browser-logs-are-incomplete)

After change `CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS` to `goog:loggingPrefs` I finnaly got all the logs.

The new capability key was described in highlights to ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8 https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can add cast to `webDriver` initialized to be `RemoteWebDriver`, and using `.setLogLevel`:

```
webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
((RemoteWebDriver) webDriver).setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import java.util.logging.Level;
```

Comment: @GennadyZyablitsev Have tried initialized with :`webDriver = new ChromeDriver();`, without parameter ?